# Remove particular class from all table rows

Tags: javascript

in which on particular tr elements i have a class "deleted_row" which should be remove from all tr elements which have that class. I gave  a id, I think which can help me to do this.

Is anyone know any method to do above thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @rajat your question is unclear!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: post your code either. keep in mind an `ID` must be unique in a webpage.

Comment: Yes, I know my question is unclear. But sorry for that.

Comment: Please tell me a method, from which i can remove all child elements particular class.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see from your question, You only want to remove particular class from all tr elements. I am assuming that, "deleted_row" class only exists in your tr element & you are assuming tbody id as your parent element. Below is jquery code for that.

```
$('#tbody').children().removeClass('deleted_row');
```

**Note:** It will remove "deleted_row" from all tr elements which contains that class, Not particuar tr elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand well you want to remove the class "deleted_row" to all  elements which have that class. To do so, you need to select those elements and remove the class:

```js
function removeClass() {
  const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.deleted_row'));
  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.classList.remove('deleted_row');
  });
}
```

```css
.deleted_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="deleted_row"><td>Row</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="deleted_row"><td>Row</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>


<button onclick="removeClass()">Remove class</button>
```